# Why fgetws can't work well with _O_U16TEXT mode?

Tags: c

I want to read the content of `_O_U16TEXT` format from `stdin`. But `fgetwc` and `fgetws` don't seem to work well with that mode.
`fgetws` return a string with `\n`. However, it doesn't consume that `\n`. As a result, the next time I called `fgetws`, it just return a '\n'. This also happens to `fgetwc`.
I want to know why `fgetws` doesn't consume `\n` but returns a string with `\n` and how to read `_O_U16TEXT` properly?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{   
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t ws[100];
    fgetws(ws, 100, stdin);
    wprintf(L"read: %s\n", ws);
    wchar_t r[100];
    fgetws(r, 100, stdin);
    wprintf(L"read: %s\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect I input two string, and save them in `ws` and `r`. But after inputing one string, the program stopped, and `r` is `\n`.

> My os is win10, compiler gcc 8.1.0.

Comment: You are supplying incorrect array size.

Comment: BTW: Also check the returnvalue of functions. Some generic advise to new users here is to take the [tour] and read [ask], though I find nothing wrong with your question.

Comment: `wchar_t *ws = (wchar_t*)malloc(100 * sizeof(wchar_t));`

Comment: You probably want to set stdout mode to _O_U16TEXT too.

Comment: By the way _O_U16TEXT and _fileno are not defined with gcc. How do you compile your program?

Comment: @selbie Thanks for your advice, I've updated my code. But my poor code is not the cause of the problem. `fgetws` still doesn't consume `\n`.

Comment: @n.m. `_fileno` is defined in `stdio.h`, and `_O_U16TEXT` is from `fcntl.h`, I can use them with gcc in win10.

Comment: What flavour of gcc are you using? I have x86_64-pc-msys and it is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the MinGW compiler. In `_O_U16TEXT` mode its `fgetws` function reads the newline character twice even though you type it once. You may want to skip every other line (check that the line you are skipping is empty, just in case).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check for every empty line, this works for me.